# 3 year old bug in SwiftUI's Navigation Bar still present. Anyone know a good workaround?

Tags: swiftui

It is well known that a trailing button on a SwiftUI navigation bar is hard to tap. Its tappable area seems to be covered by a trailing inset, making it not register taps correctly (its as if the trailing half of its tappable area is disabled).

I wrote a minimum reproducible example to make it clearer.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .navigationBarItems(  // Issue also present with `toolbar`
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Tapped!")
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                )
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(
            StackNavigationViewStyle()
        )
    }
}
```

Copy and paste this on a new Xcode project, run it on an iPhone (not a simulator, it works fine there), and try to tap the plus button, you'll see what I mean.

Anyone have a way to get around this? I've tried the usually suggested ones like `.imageScale(.large)`, overlaying a rectangle, and using other types of view with a `.onTap` method, but they don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `navigationBarItems` was deprecated at least 2 iOS versions ago try `toolbar`

Comment: This workaround works for me! .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped!")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .frame(height: 96, alignment: .trailing)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @loremipsum I'm sad to say that the issue is present with `toolbar` too.

Comment: @MichaelWang Regrettably the issue persists with your workaround. Just copied and pasted it into my example and its still there :-(. Thanks anyway though.